# Setting image margins and location based on orientation

Tags: java, optimization, android

This code is for Android but I guess anyone can take a chance at it.

It does what I want it to do. Just that I am not comfortable with its deep level of nesting and too much of value swapping.

Can this be optimized for readability or in compactness?

```
for(int imagenum, imagenum <76, imagenum++){

    if (orientation.contentEquals("landscape")
            || orientation.contentEquals("reverse landscape")) {
        params.height = imageheight;
        params.width = imagewidth;
        imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageback);
        if (imagenum <= 38) {

            params.leftMargin = imagenum * xspaceforeachimage;
            params.topMargin = 0;
        } else {
            params.leftMargin = (imagenum - 39) * xspaceforeachimage;
            params.topMargin = topMargin;
        }
    } else if (orientation.contentEquals("portrait")
            || orientation.contentEquals("reverse portrait")) {
        params.height = imagewidth;
        params.width = imageheight;
        imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagebacklaid);
        if (imagenum <= 38) {
            params.leftMargin = 0;
            params.topMargin = imagenum * xspaceforeachimage;
        } else {
            params.leftMargin = topMargin;
            params.topMargin = (imagenum - 39) * xspaceforeachimage;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What type does `orientation` have?

Comment: It has type `String`.

Comment: Something tells me something big is missing from your code above...did you truncate it? If that is literally your code, you don't need a for loop at all--just calculate everything with `imagenum=75`.

Comment: You can able to use this line 
    orientation.contains("landscape"); 
instead of this line  
    if (orientation.contentEquals("landscape") || orientation.contentEquals("reverse landscape")) 

use same thing for "portrait" condition.

Comment: and add a boolean reversed to orientation if you want to know if its reversed

Comment: @Tenfour04 - what makes me you say that you can calculate everything with imagenum = 75.That is absurd. This code lays down 78 buttons on the screen at different locations. with image num=75, the left and top margin for each button will be the same and they will overlap each other.

Comment: I know it's absurd; that's why I asked if you truncated something. `imageButton` and `params` are never reassigned inside your for loop, so they will result with whatever you give them in the last run of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't save many lines of code, but I think it's more readable and maintainable:

```
boolean landscape = orientation.contains("landscape");

for(int imagenum = 0; imagenum <76; imagenum++){

    /* Missing code that assigns params and imageButton using imageNum? */

    int shortSideMargin = imagenum * xspaceforeachimage;
    int longSideMargin = 0;
    if (imagenum >= 39)  { //new row or column, shift back and over
        shortSideMargin -= 39 * xspaceforeachimage;
        longSideMargin = topMargin;
    }

    if (landscape) {
        params.height = imageheight;
        params.width = imagewidth;
        params.leftMargin = shortSideMargin;
        params.topMargin = longSideMargin;
        imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageback);
    } else {
        params.height = imagewidth;
        params.width = imageheight;
        params.leftMargin = longSideMargin;
        params.topMargin = shortSideMargin;
        imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagebacklaid);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks buddy..definitely much cleaner and readable than mine. thanks for taking time to redo that :)

Answer (score 1):

you have:

```
orientation.contentEquals("landscape"
```

better practice for null safe:

```
"landscape".equals(orientation)
```

even better, use constants or enums!